# Format of lines when copying from PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, formatting, microsoft-word-2013, format

I'm trying to copy text from PDF file to word, however when i paste the text in word file, the lines in PDF file are "shorter", so it doesn't take up the whole line in word and i have to manually join the sentences so it looks like normal (using backspace).

I tried PDF copy paster, although it kinda works, it removed every line break so there are no paragraphs retained, but the file i am trying to copy is pretty big and i need actual paragraphs to be retained. Is there a way to make word to fit the lines as much as it can and respect the actual paragraphs as well ?

Answer (score 0):

The text in the PDF consists of absolutely positioned text fragments, and in the general case line and paragraph breaks are not specifically denoted. So the task of correctly determining them becomes more of an OCR, which is a complex task, and you'll most probably need complex software to achieve satisfactory results.

MS Word itself, for example, has the feature of importing PDF documents, but it also doesn't always recognize the breaks perfectly (for example when the text fragments are a little 'tilted', which is the case with scanned and OCR-ed documents).